# AndroidStudio 3.0: Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@dev/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :common

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

**Android Studio 3.0**

I have 3 build types:
"**release**" and "**dev**"

**project/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':common'
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

     kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$GLIDE_VERSION"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile project(':common')
}
```

But when I try to build I get the next error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@dev/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :common.

Could not resolve project :common.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :common:
     - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
         - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'dev' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
         - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
```

P.S. On Android Studio 2.3.3 my project success build and run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the Gradle build process, try to change:

```
 android {
  buildTypes {
      release {
          ...
      }
      dexOptions {
          ...
        // release & debug is in project animators
      }
      dev {
        matchingFallbacks = ["debug"]
      }
    }
}

dependencies {
'implementation project(':common')
}
```

Comment: Not help: Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@dev/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'common-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
<a href="openFile:/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@dev/compileClasspath&#39;: Failed to transform file &#39;common-release.aar&#39; to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform">Show Details</a>

Comment: Not help: Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@dev/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :common.
<a href="openFile:app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@dev/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve project :common.">Show Details</a>

Comment: Maybe it's because I has not buildType=debug? I have 2 buildType=relase and buildType=dev

Comment: Not help: :app:javaPreCompileDev
:app:compileDevJavaWithJavac\dev\Myproject\app\src\main\java\com\myproject\android\customer\api\model\CatalogAdapteJsonDeserilizer.java:9: error: package com.myproject.android.customer.common.util does not exist
import com.myproject.android.customer.common.util.GsonUtil;

Comment: I am investigating on a solution : can you try the last one?

Comment: Not help: Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@dev/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :common.
<a href="openFile:dev/myproject/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@dev/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve project :common.">Show Details</a>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157985/discussion-between-hadjkhelil-nawrez-and-alexei).

Comment: I found solution. In buildType=dev I must to add the next: 
'matchingFallbacks = ["debug"]'. In dependencies I must add: 'implementation project(':common')'

Comment: the last one didn't help you ?

Comment: I have edited it again : is it that the right answer ?

Comment: Yes, now it help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this problem maybe cause by miss match `buildTypes` between module `build.gradle` files

**app build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dev {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**common build.gradle [incorrect]**

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    // miss debug and dev config block (the reason of this problem)

    }
}
```

**common build.gradle [correct]**

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dev {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```